# XMLSignatureInput в библиотеке от СМЭВ на java

Tags: java, xml

Так как у СМЭВ есть образцовая реализация механизма их же нормализации XML в их методической рекомендации (можно глянуть [тут](http://minsvyaz.ru/uploaded/files/prilozhenie-12-k-protokolu-metodicheskie-rekomendatsii-po-rabote-so-smev-versiya-3400.pdf) пункт 12.4), то я решил для проверки собственноручной реализации ее в пыхе попробовать проверить себя, все ли правильно. 
 Проблема в том что в java я новичок и сильно путаюсь в обилии библиотек и классов, но среду худо-бедно настроил. 
 Смысл вопроса в следующем:

На входе в качестве аргумента в функцию для трансформации принимется объект класса XMLSignatureInput. После гугления и матерков я нагуглил вроде правильынй способ получить его из обычной и привычной строки (в пыхе к счастью все намного проще):

```
String xmlText = "<ns2:SenderProvidedRequestData xmlns:ns2=\"urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/1.0\" Id=\"SIGNED_BY_CONSUMER\">\n" +
                " <MessagePrimaryContent xmlns=\"urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/basic/1.0\">\n" +
                "  <SomeRequest:SomeRequest xmlns:SomeRequest=\"urn://x-artifacts-it-ru/vs/smev/test/test-business-data/1.0\">\n" +
                "   <x xmlns=\"urn://x-artifacts-it-ru/vs/smev/test/test-business-data/1.0\">qweqwe</x>\n" +
                "  </SomeRequest:SomeRequest>\n" +
                " </MessagePrimaryContent>\n" +
                "</ns2:SenderProvidedRequestData>";
        byte[] byteArray = xmlText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        XMLSignatureInput xml = new XMLSignatureInput(stream);
```

Как я понял мы преобразуем набор символов в какой-то поток и пихаем его в этот импут. Онако образцовая ХМЛ из примера той же методической рекомендации не хочет читаться механизмом трансформации. И когда делаешь вот так:

```
xml = transform.enginePerformTransform(xml);
```

То валится ошибка в стиле

```
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1]
```

Т.е. при начале чтения этого самого XMLSignatureInput он валится и не может его прочитать. Такое ощущение что нужная структура данных из текстовой ХМЛки не создается. Если кто-то работал с XMLSignatureInput или еще лучше той ОБРАЗЦОВОЙ реализацией от СМЭВ поясните пожалуйста как оно правильно делается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос с классом из тестового примера решен. Эт опочти мой первый опыт работы с джавой и возможно это можно было бы сделать проще, но я заставил его работать вот так (не забудьте поставить нужные jar):

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.NodeSet;
import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.InvalidCanonicalizerException;
import org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature;
import org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException;
import org.apache.xml.security.transforms.Transform;
import org.apache.xml.security.transforms.TransformationException;
import org.dom4j.dom.DOMDocument;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureInput;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.TransformException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.xml.security.exceptions.XMLSecurityException;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.*;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;


import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;


public class Main {



    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CanonicalizationException,
    InvalidCanonicalizerException, TransformationException,
    ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, XMLSignatureException, TransformerConfigurationException,
            TransformerException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
        SmevTransformSpi transform = new SmevTransformSpi();

        String xmlText = "Впишите сюда свю ХМЛ в виде текста";
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlText.getBytes());

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document d = db.parse(is);


        Node rootElement = d.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println("Input:");
        System.out.println(nodeToString(rootElement));



        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(rootElement);
        Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
        ByteArrayInputStream InputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());


        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStrem = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        XMLSignatureInput xml = new XMLSignatureInput(InputStream);
        String test = new String();
        xml = transform.enginePerformTransform(xml, outputStrem);
        System.out.println("Output:");
        System.out.println(outputStrem.toString());


        //System.out.println(xmlText);
    }

    private static String nodeToString(Node node) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        try {
            Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
        }
        return sw.toString();
    }
}
```

В чем подвох? В том что "образцовая" реализация алгоритма трансформации из официальной методической рекомендации не проходит тесты на правильное изменение неймспейсов и выдает что-то совсем другое.

Приведу пример прямо из методички:
**Исходник:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="style.xsl"?>
<elementOne xmlns="http://test/1" xmlns:qwe="http://test/2" xmlns:asd="http://test/3">
    <qwe:elementTwo>
        <asd:elementThree>
            <elementFour> z x c </elementFour>     
            <qqq:elementFive xmlns:qqq="http://test/2"> w w w </qqq:elementFive>
        </asd:elementThree>
        <asd:elementSix>eee</asd:elementSix>
    </qwe:elementTwo>  
</elementOne>
```

**То что должен возвращаять тест**

```
<ns1:elementOne xmlns:ns1="http://test/1"><ns2:elementTwo xmlns:ns2="http://test/2"><ns3:elementThree xmlns:ns3="http://test/3"><ns1:elementFour> z x c </ns1:elementFour><ns2:elementFive> w w w </ns2:elementFive></ns3:elementThree><ns4:elementSix xmlns:ns4="http://test/3">eee</ns4:elementSix></ns2:elementTwo></ns1:elementOne>
```

**То что возвращает "образцовая трансформация"**

```
<ns1:elementOne xmlns:ns1="http://test/1"><ns2:elementTwo xmlns:ns2="http://test/2"><ns3:elementThree xmlns:ns3="http://test/3"><ns1:elementFour> z x c </ns1:elementFour><ns2:elementFive> w w w </ns2:elementFive></ns3:elementThree><ns3:elementSix>eee</ns3:elementSix></ns2:elementTwo></ns1:elementOne>
```

Если сравнить результаты видно что неймспейсы формирутся не правильно. И, так как в моей реализации СМЭВ принимает сообщения без аттача с трансформацией по методичке (хотя все еще есть затык с аттачем) а не в виде как выдает класс на Java, то скоере всего образцовая реализация нифига не образцовая.